# Is there any default key in vim to create a new line after current line and remain in normal mode?

Tags: vim

While editing code I always need this feature: create a new line after current line, move cursor to a new line (saving curent indention!) and remain in normal mode. For example (assuming █ is a cursor):

```
function a() {
    foon█tion()
}
```

After I type the command, I need to turn out like this:

```
function a() {
    foonction()
    █
}
```

I can achieve the same effect if I, for example, press `<Enter><Esc>` while being in Insert mode with cursor on the end of a line. The `o` command also acts similar, but it deletes indention after I quit insert mode. So I need a single keypress to insert one line down.

inb4 nmap: I know how to map a command for doing such thing, but I'm wondering if there is a standard way to do this.

Comment: FYI, `S` will start *INSERT* mode at the right indentation level.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Also you can use [`<C-o> o` combo](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_newline_without_entering_insert_mode)

Answer (score 24):

There is no such key, but it turns out that we can do this - sans indentation - with four keystrokes: `:pu_<Enter>`

This is a [vim faq](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vimfaq.html) question, where the answer is to use the Ex command `:put`:

> 12.15. How do I insert a blank line above/below the current line without entering insert mode?
>
> You can use the ":put" ex command to insert blank lines. For example, try

```
:put =''
:put! =''
```

> For more information, read :help :put

`:put` puts the text from the given register after the current line and leaves you in normal mode. `:put!` puts the text on a line above the current line.

The examples above are using the `expression` register `=` to send an empty string to the `put` command. We can trim this down by using vim's *black hole* register, `_`: `:put _`.

Finally, this can be abbreviated to: `:pu_<Enter>` and `:pu!_<Enter>`.

See also: `:help registers`.

Finally, note that this is also a feature of Tim Pope's *unimpaired* plugin.

From the unimpaired README:

> There are linewise mappings. `[<Space>` and `]<Space>` add newlines before and after the cursor line. `[e` and `]e` exchange the current line with the one above or below it.

Comment: The above `:put` commands can be shortened as `:pu_` and `:pu!_`.

Comment: There is a very similar mapping (`]<space>`) along with many other useful mappings provided by Tim Pope's unimpaired.vim plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590